# Image is not updating in Image control windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I have image link like http://images.test.com/profiles/profile_28044497_75sq_1359604729.jpg" now i want to show this image in image control  in windows phone 8. 
the problem is that when i will open page it showing image and then i will change profile image and save it on server and the image is saved successfully and then i will navigate to another page and then profile page that i am not able to  show updated image  but when i debug my code i am getting new updated image but the image control is showing previous image i for all images my image url is same am using following code:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Width="140" Height="120"  Tap="Image_Tap" Name="image1"/>
                    </StackPanel>

       if (isNetworkConnection())
            {
                var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);

                string flag = rootObject.flag;
                string msg = rootObject.message;

                if (flag.Equals("1"))
                {

                    foreach (var temp in rootObject.result)
                    {


                        imb.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(temp.image));
                        image1.Source = imb.ImageSource;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent caching, the easiest way is to add a dummy parameter to the url and change it every time. For instance:

```
imb.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(temp.image + "?" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString()));
```